# Интернет магазин на Java. Выборка товаров по фильтру.

Tags: база-данных, java-ee, архитектура, servlet

Допустим у  меня в БД есть таблица Product, в которой есть столбцы - атрибуты обєкта: attr1, attr2, attr3.
Я хочу сделать так, чтоб пользователь мог фильтровать выборку товаров по атрибутам(фильтр бар, в большинстве интернет магазинов есть):

[image: Фильтр бар]

Значения - val, у меня хранятся в БД - это значения столбцов attr. Я их подтягиваю из БД когда пользователь на страницу заходит.
Вот, теперь надо то же сделать с самими атрибутами, то есть, мне надо отобразить названия столбцов. Но вопрос в том, как ? Кроме того, названия столбцов в базе на английском, в мне надо, чтоб на русском отображалось. Захардкодить названия - не самый лучший вариант, ведь при добавлении в базу нового столбца придется менять jsp.
Наверняка есть какое то решения, может кто сталкивался с этим или просто знает как лучше сделать, буду рад помощи. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вытягивать в сервлете названия столбцов, например:

http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/jdbc-mysql/ColumnName.shtml

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19095179/873481

Если нужно отображать перевод, создайте, например, Map. Там будете хранить пары значений названий столбцов ключ-англ и значение-рус. И, соответственно с нужным значением бд для вывода, будете выводить русское значение столбца по заданному англ.-ключу из бд.